# MobileFirst POST request from Swift to JS adapter

Tags: swift, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Has anyone managed to invoke MobileFirst JS adapters from Swift with the POST method?

i.e.

```
let request = WLResourceRequest(URL: NSURL(string: “/adapters/myadapter”), method: WLHttpMethodPost)

request.sendWithFormParameters(formParams) { (WLResponse response, NSError error) -> Void in
```

How should we construct the `formParams` in Swift and the adapter method in JS? We have been unable to extract the form parameters when the adapter is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your form parameters should include only 1 parameter called “params” that contains a `string` representing an `array`.

For example:

```
request.sendWithFormParameters([ "params" : "[\"param1\", \"param2\"]" ])
```

Comment: @IdanAdar Is this also true with Android? What was the logic behind moving to this new way to set query params?